# Cannot create Managed Apache Airflow Environment on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow

I followed the instruction on AWS to create one Airflow environment but failed. It said that I need to ask my admin for access while I'm using my own account. What does it mean? [image]

**NOTE**: I'm using the AWS function included in Udacity Nanodegree Program.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of how it is mentioned in udacity. However, as highlighted in the error message, you (or your admin) should add create access in the policy associated with the role that creates airflow environment.

More details here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-create-role.html